# Unwrap nested Obsevable

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to request service for data with interval.
I'm using Observable.interval to achieve this, so on each emit I want to request a service:

```
 Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Schedulers.io())
                .map(tick -> restService.getData());
```

My restService.getData() returns `Single<MyData>`, so here I've got

```
Observable<Single<MyData>>
```

but i only need a response from server, which is `Single<MyData>`, to subscribe on it.

I've ended up with this code:

```
  Single.fromObservable(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Schedulers.io())
            .map(tick -> restService.getData())
            .flatMap(dataSingle-> dataSingle.map(data-> data)
                    .toObservable()));
```

But this is looks too ugly.

Is there any way to reach such result without doing all of this actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you try to achieve here, maybe this?

```
Single.timer(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(tick -> restService.getData())
```

or this?

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapSingle(tick -> restService.getData())
```

Comment: The second option is definetely what I need! Shame on me for not reading RxJava manual properly.